# Get sum of all the records before certain record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have something like this in my database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("561c2ca2153678d113d03077"), "title" : "Level 8", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(25)}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5615980b153678d113d02d61"), "title" : "Level 9", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(40)}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56159796153678d113d02d60"), "title" : "Level 10", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(55)}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5613f5ad153678d113d01f4a"), "title" : "Level 11", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(70)}
```

So I would like to get sum of all rewardCoins under "Level 11"
That total should be 55+40+25 = 120

I'm wondering how can I get this with mongo shell ?

I was trying something like:

```
db.userlevels.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
        "title": {$lt: "Level 11"}
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {"name": "Level 11"},
            "totalAmount": { $sum: "$rewardCoins"}
        }
    }
])
```

But I'm not getting what I'am expecting...
Hint or solution would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You won't get accurate results with string comparisons. It would be best if you could store your levels in a numerical field then your filter query would work otherwise with the above schema, the `$match` pipeline will only pipe the document with `"Level 10"` to the next pipeline since comparing strings the logic `("Level 9" < "Level 10")` is falsey.

Comment: can this work if I match it with object id (_id) @chridman ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider introducing additional numeric field just to store level:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("561c2ca2153678d113d03077"), "title" : "Level 8", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(25), level: 8}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5615980b153678d113d02d61"), "title" : "Level 9", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(40), level: 9}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56159796153678d113d02d60"), "title" : "Level 10", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(55), level: 10}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5613f5ad153678d113d01f4a"), "title" : "Level 11", "rewardCoins" : NumberLong(70), level: 11}
```

Having it as a part of title and then comparing strings is a bit strange. Then this aggregation query should do the job:

```
db.userlevels.aggregate([{$match: {"level": {$lt: 11}}}, {$group: {"_id": null, "totalAmount": { $sum: "$rewardCoins"}}}])
```